# "Extension" of the first Data Unit

Tags: fits

I'm starting to study the FITS format and I'm in the proccess of reading the [Definition of FITS](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/standard30/fits_standard30aa.pdf) document.

I know that a FITS file can have one or more HDUs, the primary being the first one and the extensions being the following ones (if there is more than one HDU), I also know that for the extensions there is a mandatory keyword in the header (`XTENSION`) that let us know if the Data Unit is an Image, Binary Table or ASCII Table, but how can I know what is the Data Type (Image, Binary Table or ASCII Table) of the first HDU?

I don't understand why `XTENSION` isn't a mandatory keyword in the primary header.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your interest in FITS?  If you're thinking of using it for some new application I would gently suggest against it, unless there's some specific operational requirement to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The "type" of the `PRIMARY` HDU is essentially `IMAGE` in most cases.  From v3.0 of the standard:

> 3.3.2. Primary data array
>   The primary data array, if present, shall consist of a single data
>   array with from 1 to 999 dimensions (as specified by the NAXIS
>   keyword defined in Sect. 4.4.1). The random groups convention
>   in the primary data array is a more complicated structure and
>   is discussed separately in Sect. 6. The entire array of data values
>   are represented by a continuous stream of bits starting with
>   the first bit of the first data block. Each data value shall consist
>   of a fixed number of bits that is determined by the value of
>   the BITPIX keyword (Sect. 4.4.1). Arrays of more than one dimension
>   shall consist of a sequence such that the index along
>   axis 1 varies most rapidly, that along axis 2 next most rapidly,
>   and those along subsequent axes progressively less rapidly, with that along axis m, where m is the value of NAXIS, varying least
>   rapidly. There is no space or any other special character between
>   the last value on a row or plane and the first value on the next
>   row or plane of a multi-dimensional array. Except for the location
>   of the first element, the array structure is independent of the
>   FITS block structure. This storage order is shown schematically
>   in Fig. 1 and is the same order as in multi-dimensional arrays in
>   the Fortran programming language (ISO 2004). The index count
>   along each axis shall begin with 1 and increment by 1 up to the
>   value of the NAXISn keyword (Sect. 4.4.1).
>   If the data array does not fill the final data block, the remainder
>   of the data block shall be filled by setting all bits to zero.
>   The individual data values shall be stored in big-endian byte order
>   such that the byte containing the most significant bits of the
>   value appears first in the FITS file, followed by the remaining
>   bytes, if any, in decreasing order of significance.

Though  it isn't until later on (in section 7.1) that it makes this connection:

> 7.1. Image extension
>   The FITS image extension is nearly identical in structure to the
>   the primary HDU and is used to store an array of data. Multiple
>   image extensions can be used to store any number of arrays in a
>   single FITS file. The first keyword in an image extension shall
>   be `XTENSION= ’IMAGE ’`.

It isn't immediately apparent what it means by "nearly identical" here.  I guess the only difference is that the `PRIMARY` HDU may also have the aformentioned "random groups" structure, whereas with `IMAGE` extension HDU's `PCOUNT` is always `0` and `GCOUNT` is always `1`.

You'll only rarely see the "random groups" convention.  This is sort of a precursor to the `BINTABLE` format.  It was used traditionally in radio interferometry data, but hardly at all outside that.

The reason for all this is for backwards compatibility with older versions of FITS that predate even the existence of extension HDUs.  Many FITS-based formats don't put any data in the `PRIMARY` HDU and use the primary header only for metadata keywords that pertain to the entire file (e.g. most HST data).